# Get getting triggered automatically in Angular components

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ADMIN_MENUS } from '../pages/pages-menu';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss'],
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  menu = ADMIN_MENUS;

  constructor(private readonly authS: AuthService) {
    alert('constructor');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    alert('init');
    if (this.authS.isAuth) {
      this.authS.getNewTokenPair().subscribe(
        (d) => console.log(d),
        (err) => console.log(err),
      );
    }
  }
  private get r() {
    alert('r');
    return;
  }
  set c(c: any) {
    alert('c');
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "oro-admin",
  "version": "4.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng serve --open",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 1 --disable-host-check",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@filestack/angular": "^1.0.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "4.4.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "@nebular/security": "4.4.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "4.4.0",
    "@ngrx/data": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "7.2.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "2.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "echarts": "^4.0.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "filestack-js": "^3.14.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.7",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "intl-tel-input": "^14.1.0",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "2.0.8",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.3.5",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^2.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "subsink": "^1.0.1",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Getters are getting triggered automatically in all components. I don't know what could be causing it.

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPH_B3dNV64nviZBqLigbE91o_nUlgEG-uMVPwamMK3LaJfHlPgoqhznNqfo7D0LQ?key=aEtIZGY0eDNSbTJZSzE4MENMeDY2emxSRm5MTm9R

Above is a video link cause I know it sounds crazy

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to get a clue what is calling the getter method?

Comment: I uninstalled  "@ngrx/data": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.6.0", and the bug is gone

Answer (score 0):

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
  metaReducers,
  **runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    strictActionImmutability: true,
  },**
}),
```

runtimeChecks were the thing causing it I dont know how or why in my investigation I only found that its the thing causing it